# Disable return in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was curious if there is a good way to disable returning in a **C** function.

This is not something I would often want to do, but there are cases where large complex functions should not return within specific blocks of code, and I want to ensure that.

Typically this is to ensure cleanup functions run or that state is not left invalid.

If you have many people working on the code, having some compiler check can be handy since this can slip through by accident.

```
 some_function(void)
 {
     /* ... code ... */

 #define return __noreturn__  /* any unknown identifier */
     { int return; (void)return; }  /* avoids gcc's '-Wunused-macros' */

     /* ... code which _can't_ return ... */

 #undef return

     /* ... code which _can_ return ... */

 }
```

This works. but is fairly ugly and I wouldn't want to use this for anything besides a quick local test.

Is there some way to setup macros which disable return end enable again? (maybe using some poison _Pragma?, but it has to be able to un-poison too).

```
 some_function(void)
 {
     /* ... code ... */
     RETURN_DISABLE;
     /* ... code which _can't_ return ... */
     RETURN_ENABLE;
     /* ... code which _can_ return ... */

 }
```

*Note* 1) I'm aware that in most cases there are better solutions to this, which involve refactoring code, but I think there are some cases where this assurance is useful still.

*Note* 2) Using `goto` could still bypass cleanup code, but I'd consider that case out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: Just doing a text search for "return" would work for a quick local test. If you can store the return value in a variable, and discipline yourself to always return that variable, then if it works with the blocks you have you could always just delay defining that variable until after the code that must not return.

Comment: Yep, mostly this is good-enough, Though a local search for `return` wont find `return` within a macro (the example I linked above _will_). However returning within macros is something I try to avoid.

Comment: True. If you're really paranoid, you can just have the compiler output the preprocessed source and search that instead. If you put some kind of labels around the offending sections, you could automate a test like that.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths, right, but that means having to setup extra tooling when all developers run before committing changes. If its possible to do this with preprocessor (or even compiler extensions), I would prefer to go down that path. But I don't consider this paranoia, from my experience bugs caused by returning out of a function, forgetting to free resources are very common, while this wont solve that, it can at least mitigate it in some cases.

Comment: I would think that what you want would have to be a compiler specific extension.  Wrapper macros used consistently might give you something close to what you want, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: "large complex functions should not return within specific blocks of code..." strikes me as an XY Problem.  This problem would likely be better addressed with better-decomposed functions, static analysis and judicious use of `goto`.

Comment: I doubt you can solve that within the language. I'd say: consider using clang analyzer, consider writing a pass for that. (i.e.: make a function attribute within clang and whenever clang analyzer finds this attribute start your analysis pass)

Comment: re **I doubt you can solve that within the language**, I already did solve this in my initial post, just not in a very clean way. But point taken - using some external static checking tools can work too, its just that this needs to run periodically and on a large codebase this can take quite some time.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve an issue with a compiler that should be solved via code reviews and a coding standard.

It is a good rule of thumb that functions shouldn't have multiple exit points.  This makes them harder to reason about and also harder to make sure that clean up code runs (your problem here).  Also if the function is so large that you think you you might miss a return statement then it may well need to be split in to smaller functions.

e.g. You could have

```
int some_func(...)
{
      init_some_func(...);
      err = some_func_work(...)
      clean_up_some_func(...);
      return err;
}
```

or something similar.  Now a return from the working function will always lead to the clean up being done.

Comment: You can check for using uninitialized variables with code reviews and standards too, nevertheless automated checks can be useful (hence `-Wuninitialized`), but you are right - in most cases its better to split the function out.

Comment: @ideasman42: I would definitely compile with -Wall and -Werror and use the compiler for what it is good at.  But the compiler can't know that you want to run some section of clean up code.  That's a logic error.  And for that you will have to use other methods.  Besides, how can you be sure that you have set DISABLE_RETURN() in the right place!

Comment: You are assuming that Im attempting to have the compiler think for me, of course the compiler can't know, but I know, and I want to indicate this to the compiler. I can just add some comment in the code, if that comment can be backed by a warning - I see that as an advantage. In the same way I can add a comment on a function that its return should always be used, or use the `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` attribute.